# Use existing sub-domain for new hosting plan

Tags: dns, dreamhost, bluehost

Suppose I have a domain test.com in the bluehost server. 
Now I want to purchase a new hosting plan in dreamhost.
While purchasing the plan, I want to have domain name for new server as server2.test.com or test.com/server2.
What will I need to do for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into the dns manager for your account and configure a CNAME or DNAME entry that points server2.test.com to the ip address (or domain name) for your server at dreamhost.  I use godaddy.com for my domain names and it's very easy there.

A CNAME is like a symbolic link or alias for dns.

For more information, see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cname